# Why are three inductors and one capacitor needed to bias this transisor (radio frequency)?

Tags: rf

Below is the circuit.  I don't understand its purpose.

[image]

Comment: It’s rather hard to answer the question with no component values  but essentially the inductors present a higher impedance than their DC resistance, so the input impedance of the amplifier is relatively high and the output impedance relatively low without the need for a significant DC current through the transistor.

Comment: Many good answers and comments here.  I will just add this: study simple BJT/FET biasing topics first, then BJT/FET amplifiers, THEN venture into RF BJT/FET.  Jumping into this design is slightly more advanced.  The concept of biasing and Ce bypassing is introduced in introductory BJT/FET texts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inductors do not affect the DC "bias", the resistors do. The inductors are used to filter high frequencies, (RFC = Radio frequency chokes). The RFC inductors control the entry (or exit) of high frequency signals from certain points in the circuit.

R1 an R2 form a DC voltage divider that biases the base of the transistor. Re helps to determine the DC emitter current, Rc helps to determine the DC voltage at the collector

The capacitor does just what the caption says, "a bypassed emitter resistor".  Higher frequency signals will pass through the capacitor and "bypass" the resistor Re.

Answer (score 5):

What this image is demonstrating is the use of RF chokes to block RF energy, and a capacitor to pass RF energy.

In an RF amplifier you want the RF signal to have a low impedance path through the base-emitter circuit, and a high impedance path through the base bias network and collector load. The bypass capacitor provides a low impedance path through the emitter circuit, while the RF chokes block the signal from being attenuated in the bias network and provide a high impedance collector load for maximum gain.

In a real-world circuit you would not use separate chokes for each of the base resistors, you would connect the resistors together and use a single choke from their junction to the base.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIIDTZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>